# Data not save on database

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

In my website when someone register he give some values like 1st name,last name,email, password etc. Which save in `auth_User` database. I want to make a new model Profile which is child of User model. and its have some new fields.

**models.py**

```
class Profile(User):
    image = models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True, upload_to="profile/")
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=255,null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True,blank=True,)
    mobile_no = models.CharField(max_length=10,null=True,blank=True,)
    website_url = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True,blank=True,)
    facebook_url = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True,blank=True,)
    twitter_url = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True,blank=True,)
    linkdin_url = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True,blank=True,)
```

**forms.py**

```
class UserEditForm(UserChangeForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={"class":"form-control"}) )
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"form-control"}))
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"form-control"}))

    
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('first_name','last_name','username','email','password','image','address','mobile_no','bio','website_url','facebook_url','twitter_url','linkdin_url')
        
        widgets = {
            "username" : forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"form-control","placeholder":"write title of your posts"}), 
            "website_url" : forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"form-control","placeholder":"write title of your posts"}), 
            "facebook_url" : forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"form-control","placeholder":"write title of your posts"}), 
            "twitter_url" : forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"form-control","placeholder":"write title of your posts"}), 
            "linkdin_url" : forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"form-control","placeholder":"write title of your posts"}), 
            # # "title_tag" : forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"form-control"}), 
            # # "author" : forms.HiddenInput(), 
            # # "image" : forms.Select(attrs={"class":"custom-file"}), 
            # "catagory" : forms.Select(choices=choices,attrs={"class":"form-control"}), 
            "bio" : forms.Textarea(attrs={"class":"form-control"}), 
        }
```

**urls.py**

```
path('edit_profile/',UserEditView.as_view(),name="editProfile"),
```

**views.py**

```
class UserEditView(UpdateView):
    form_class = UserEditForm
    template_name = 'edit_profile.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('editProfile')

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user
```

**edit_profile.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %} Edit Profile... {% endblock title %}
{% block content %}
<style>
    label[for=id_password],.helptext,#id_password {
      display: none;
    }
    </style>
    
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<h1>Edit Profile... </h1>
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p}}
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Update Profile</button>
</form>
{% else %}
<h3> You are not loged in</h3>
{% endif %}
{% endblock content %}
```

But from template when I want to add some value on these new fields, it does not save in `app_Profile` table of my database. but I can do this from admin panel

I also try to make signup page using profile table. but still not work

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action=".">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p}}
<button type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-secondary">Update Profile</button>
```

Try this.